# how in runtime dynamically create rest resource in Jersey 1.x

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Does Jersey 1.x has an API for programmatic creation of REST resource?
I found it in Jersey 2.x API:
[Chapter 13. Programmatic API for Building Resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html) , however i can't find it in Jersey 1.x.

Comment: Wondering, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: you need to upgrade your Jersey to 2.x